# Detectar não caracteres em uma string

Tags: php, string

Como faço para *detectar a existência* de não-caracteres como esse em uma string? `�*�v��R�<�`

Comment: tem o código e se tiver poste na questão para ajudar na resposta?

Comment: é um código de encryption/decryption usando base varias funcoes e chaves.. Entretanto quando a desencriptacao nao funciona ela retorna esses caracteres, quero que quando isso aconteça ele repita a função até ele retornar a string desencriptada e para eu fazer isso preciso que ele faca uma checagem pra ver se a string resultante possui esses caracteres estranhos..

Comment: Poste o código, se não fica difícil ajudar

Comment: Se estas a ter uma saída dessas é porque, em principio, tens alguma coisa mal no código. Para um encriptação/desencriptação perfeita a string inicial tem de ser igual a final depois de encriptar e desencriptar, respetivamente.
Isso que queres é um género de uma gambiarra, que pode acabar por dar asneira futuramente.

Comment: Qual a saída que voce quer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caracteres ASCII "regulares" vão do [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) `20` ao `7F`:

[image: Imagem da tabela ASCII]

<sup>Créditos da imagem para [Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table.svg).</sup>

Assim sendo, um método prático passa por verificar se todos os caracteres na *string* estão dentro desse intervalo ASCII, onde para o efeito podemos fazer uso de uma expressão regular:

Exemplo onde os caracteres estão fora da lista:

```php
$string = "�*�v��R�<�";

if (preg_match('/[^\x20-\x7f]/', $string)) {
  echo "Correu mal, chamar função novamente!".PHP_EOL;   // vai entrar aqui
}
else {
  echo "Todos os caracteres são legíveis!".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Exemplo onde os caracteres estão dentro da lista:

```php
$string = "HGKER%(()W(/T%&)WREGDG";

if (preg_match('/[^\x20-\x7f]/', $string)) {
  echo "Correu mal, chamar função novamente!".PHP_EOL;
}
else {
  echo "Todos os caracteres são legíveis!".PHP_EOL;      // vai entrar aqui
}
```

---

Exemplos a funcionar no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/8OLpYK).

Answer (score 2):

Para detectar caracteres numa string vc pode usar a função ***[preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)***:

```
$numero = '/(1|2|345|67|7890)/';
$frase = 'abcdefgh ijklmno pqrstu vxz';

echo preg_match($palavra, $frase);
```

Porém estes caracteres que vocÊ quer identificar, tem haver com o charset do seu banco ou do seu código, provavelmente, modificando um dos dois estes caracteres não aparecerão mais:

Você pode setar o charset no HTML:

```
>meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Você pode setar o charset no PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

E você pode setar o charset no MySQL:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); //("servidor", "usuário", "senha" definidos no banco de dados)

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8")
```

E caso esteja usando PDO:

```
$conn = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bancoTeste', //dsn
                 'root', //user
                 '123456', //senha
                 array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") // opções PDO
              );
```

Answer (score 2):

No php existem algumas funções para detectar caracteres que não são imprimíveis:

- [ctype_print() — Verifica se os caracteres são imprimíveis](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ctype-print.php)
- [ctype_cntrl() — Verifica se os caracteres são de controle](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ctype-cntrl.php)
- [ctype_graph() — Verifica se os caracteres são imprimíveis exceto
  espaço](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ctype-graph.php)
- [ctype_punct() — Verifica se é um caractere imprimível que
  não é whitespace ou alfanumério](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ctype-punct.php)